# Filename from Template Generator in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a filename from template generator.

I would like to create a template such as:

```
/path/to/my/file/{{ dir_id }}/is/here/{{ file_id }}
```

And then use regular expressions to find these keys and match the key against a dictionary.

I would like to do this elegantly as possible and it seems like something like this should work.

```
s = re.compile(r'\{\{*?P<key>*?\}\})
s.findall(template)
```

But, this isn't finding anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure regex's are the most appropriate solution to this problem. What is wrong with a traditional [format string](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)?

```
 "/path/to/my/file/%(dir_id)s/is/here/%(file_id)s" % \
         {"dir_id": "dir", "file_id": "fileId"}
```

Comment: haha, thank you!  I knew I was making this harder than it should be